# Replace multiple strings with dictionary while avoiding substring matches

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have several text-like files, in which I want to find and replace a bunch of strings based on a dictionary. Based on [this suggestion](https://gist.github.com/carlsmith/b2e6ba538ca6f58689b4c18f46fef11c), I made a simple replacement function:

```
def rep_strings(string, subs):
    substrings = sorted(subs, key=len, reverse=True)
    regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, substrings)))
    return regex.sub(lambda match: subs[match.group(0)], string)
    
for file in filelist:
    print(f"Modifying {file}...")
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        old = f.read()
        
    new = rep_strings(old, subs)
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(new)
```

This works well enough in most cases. However, I've realised that several of the strings in the actual dictionary of replacements I need to use are sub-strings of others (both of other target strings, and of replacement strings). For example:

```
subs = {
    'hello': 'goodbye',
    'hello world' : 'hello world how are you',
    'foo': 'foobar',
    'foobar': 'barbar',
    'baz': 'hello foo'
}
```

I haven't tested this fully on my actual files but am worried that it could fail in two ways:

1. Replacing substrings of targets rather than the full targets
2. Replacing substrings of replacements as if they were targets, which I don't want (e.g. in example above, ending up replacing `baz` with `goodbye foo` instead of `hello foo`, or `hello world` with `goodbye world how are you` instead of `hello world how are you`)

I think the function goes from longest to shortest target string, which should prevent problem (1) but at the cost of problem (2), right? How can I do this avoiding *both* potential problems?

Comment: If you do longest matches first it should work fine. Problem 2 doesn't happen because the regex isn't backtracking after finding a match, so when you call `rep_strings("baz", subs)` you get the expected `'hello foo'` and `rep_strings("hello world", subs)` gives me `'hello world how are you'`. Voting to close as no longer reproducible.

Comment: I think this ligne saves you from the issue you're worried about `substrings = sorted(subs, key=len, reverse=True)` it basically order them by lengths and the way regex engine works when finding the pipe is testing the first pattern then the second thus `hello world` then `hello`

Comment: @ggorlen you don't call `rep_strings` on each target / key - it gets called on the entire text that you're doing the multiple simultaneous find & replace on (in my case, each text-like file).

Comment: Exactly, as long as it's all processed once like in your example you're good.

Comment: I guess I'm not 100% sure of how the regex engine works with the pipes; maybe it inherently takes care of the problem? Does it 1) identify all matches, allowing any given part of the text string to only be part of one match, and then substitute them all at once? or 2) substitute matches as it goes?